# Science behind Beta Alanine for Running

Tags: running, supplements, speed, muscle-endurance

Is anyone familiar with good research on beta alanine supplementation for improving running performance? I am trying to determine if this is a supplement worth taking and I have only found minimal amounts of research that seem to be more anecdotal that fact based.

Comment: Asking about experience with beta alanine is more opinion based than we really handle here, however, you could reword your question to ask about the research documented effects of beta alanine on aerobic performance, or something like that.

Comment: Just edited the question.  Hopefully this is more on par.

Comment: Given that the challenge you present is that you have found minimal research that seems anecdotal and not fact based, asking us here for anecdotes and not fact based research seems backwards (and still off topic). Focusing the question to deal with good research on beta alanine would both better resolve your curiosity about it and make your question on topic. I've put in an edit that focuses your question on the research rather than anecdote and submitted it for reopening review.